# Как решить проблему с подключением фрагмента HTML к основному HTML используя ng-include?

Tags: angular, npm

У меня есть один большой HTML файл, который я решил декомпозировать(разбить на несколько не больших логических HTML фрагментов) и подключить их все одном файле. Для этого я решил использовать компонент **'ng-include'**, вот фрагмент кода, как я его вызываю из глобального HTML файла **app.component.html:** ...

`<ng-include src="'connect.html'"></ng-include>`

при запуске, я получаю такую ошибку....

```
message: "\u001b[96msrc/app/app.component.html\u001b[0m:\u001b[93m104\u001b[0m:\u001b[93m13\u001b[0m - \u001b[91merror\u001b[0m\u001b[90m NG8001: \u001b[0m'ng-include' is not a known element:\n1. If 'ng-include' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.\n2. If 'ng-include' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.\n\n\u001b[7m104\u001b[0m             <ng-include src=\"'connect.html'\"></ng-include>\n\u001b[7m   \u001b[0m \u001b[91m            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\u001b[0m\n\n  \u001b[96msrc/app/app.component.ts\u001b[0m:\u001b[93m17\u001b[0m:\u001b[93m16\u001b[0m\n    \u001b[7m17\u001b[0m   templateUrl: './app.component.html',\n    \u001b[7m  \u001b[0m \u001b[96m               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\u001b[0m\n    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.\n"
```

если я пробую такой вариант, то у меня ни чего не происходит, фрагмент не подключен (в данном случае ошибки нет) ...

```
<div ng-include src="'connect.html'"></div>
```

Файл connects.html расположен, там же где основной HTML **app.component.html**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мои текущие окружение:

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.10
Node: 16.11.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.1.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1202.10 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.2.10 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.2.10 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.2.10 (cli-only)
```

Я думаю что надо в файл **app.component.ts** добавить модуль ng-include...? но я ни где не могу найти информации об этом...

Как можно решить эту проблему с загрузкой HTML кода в основной HTML код с использованием ng-include?

Смотрел сюда:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943471/what-is-the-correct-syntax-of-ng-include
- https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-include.asp
- http://angular-doc.herokuapp.com/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

В официальной документации, к сожалению то же не нашел ответ на свой вопрос...

- https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/docs/api/ng.directive:ngInclude#Usage
- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

---

ЗЫ. Вот app.module.ts с добавленным **CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA**, теперь  ошибку не выдает, но и указанный HTML не подгружается...

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table'
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatGridListModule,
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Спасибо за помощь!

---

**Update: Ответ привел снизу.**

Comment: С ангуляром не работал, но думаю имеет смысл обратить внимание на подсказку в тексте ошибки: `If 'ng-include' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.\n2. If 'ng-include' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message` :)

Comment: Меня еще смущает наличие одинарных кавычек в путях в `<ng-include src="'connect.html'"></ng-include>`. Разве это неправильно? Думаю, так будет правильно: `<ng-include src="connect.html"></ng-include>`

Comment: кавычки ('***') должны быть в обоих вариантах ( я подправил вопрос)... так же я смотрел в документации об этом по данной директиве... хотя без них тоже пробовал.... ни чего не меняется... По ошибки я предполагаю что надо на уровне модулей в файле "app.module.ts" подключить ngInclude но пока ни где не нашел об этом информацию...., хотя 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' сейчас попробую разобраться как добавить это в модуль '@NgModule.schemas'

Comment: добавил 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' в  app.module.ts, теперь ошибка пропала.... но и HTML не подключается.... , походу ведь это внутренняя директива, а не сторонний компонент (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После детального изучения https://angular.io/guide/ я понял, что ng-include или ngInclude не используется в последней версии Angular, вместо этого ввели более гибкое понятие - биндинга (bindings)... более подробней можно прочесть по этой ссылке https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-targets, а так же  ознакомиться с рабочим примером, как можно реализовать различные привязки и вызовы на конкретной страницы (при этом с возможность передавать между этими сущностями различные данные(объекты))....

Решение  вопроса с bindings выглядит так:
необходимо в корне /src/app создать новый компонент, следующий коммандой:

```
ng g component connect
```

теперь у нас структура проекта будет выглядеть вот так....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после этого в файле app.component.html, можно через тэг app-connect:

```
<app-connect></app-connect>
```

вызвать содержимое указанного HTML расположенного в файле **connect.component.html** - данный тэг  это условный путь до созданного класса **\app\connect**

В созданном файле connect.component.html написать следующие:

```
<p>HI<\p>
```

И при запуске, у Вас на основной странице отобразиться приветствие с подключенного компонента.